Can I create a devcontainer with all the required plugins?
As I understand the devcontainer documentation the devcontainer can /should contain extensions specific to the language I am coding.
I created a devcontainer for .net and C# using the wizard, and got the following devcontainer.json, as well as a dockerfile extending mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:1-8.0-bookworm and a docker-compose.yml in which I see no extensions. Is there a way I can predefine the extensions in the files in order to ease switching PCs / onboarding developers?
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/dotnet-mssql
{
    "name": ".NET (C#), Node.js (TypeScript) & MS SQL",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
            // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
            "settings": {
                "mssql.connections": [
                    {
                        "server": "localhost,1433",
                        "database": "",
                        "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
                        "user": "sa",
                        "password": "P@ssw0rd",
                        "emptyPasswordInput": false,
                        "savePassword": false,
                        "profileName": "mssql-container"
                    }
                ]
            },

            // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
            "extensions": [
                "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
                "ms-mssql.mssql"
            ]
        }
    },

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [5000, 5001],
    // "portsAttributes": {
    //      "5001": {
    //          "protocol": "https"
    //      }
    // }

    // postCreateCommand.sh parameters: $1=SA password, $2=dacpac path, $3=sql script(s) path
    "postCreateCommand": "bash .devcontainer/mssql/postCreateCommand.sh 'P@ssw0rd' './bin/Debug/' './.devcontainer/mssql/'"

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}


